# Is there a nice way to unwrap a Maybe value that is inside of a tuple?

Tags: haskell

The signature I'm looking for is `(Maybe a, b) -> (a, b)`, which hoogle returns [no results](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(Maybe%20a%2C%20b)%20-%3E%20(a%2C%20b)) for. I can easily write my own as

```hs
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

fromJustTuple :: (Maybe a, b) -> (a, b)
fromJustTuple (a, b) = (fromJust a, b)
```

The context is that I'm using [updateLookupWithKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:updateLookupWithKey) on a `Map` where I can guarantee that the keys I'm querying exist. I could say

```hs
let (Just x, myMap') = updateLookupWithKey f k myMap
```

, but then I'd have to disable `incomplete-uni-patterns`, which I don't want to do.

Backing up a bit, this may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'm happy to hear so and learn about a different, more idiomatic approach.

Comment: `updateLookupWithKey` from `Data.Map` is bizarre.  The fact it returns the new value if the key is updated but the old value if it's deleted makes no sense, and the authors of `Data.IntMap`, for example, decided this was such stupid behavior they consistently return the old value even though it breaks "compatibility" with `Data.Map`.  Can you provide some context for how you're using `updateLookupWithKey` that you're in a situation where you don't know if you're updating or deleting a key and yet it's important to get the new value in the former case but the old value in the latter case?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I'm actually only updating. I agree that the delete behavior is strange, but it doesn't apply in my particular case. The full context is that I'm using a `Map Char Int` to count key occurrences. The only things I'm doing are incr and decr, so `f` is either `\_ x -> Just (x-1)` or `\_ x -> Just (x+1)`. It just seems like a really common use case that I would know all of my keys a priori and not want to have to unwrap a `Maybe` everytime I issue an update. The fact that I didn't immediately find such a function makes me think I may be missing something.

Comment: You could write fromJustTuple as `first fromJust` (where `first` is from [Control.Arrow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first)). Ultimately, I think your problem is that although you "can guarantee that the keys [you're] querying exist", you can't prove this to the type system, so unless you can change this, you're going to have to rely on unsafe functions like `fromJust`, or get incomplete pattern match warnings.

Comment: @Joe I'm still in the process of learning haskell and haven't gotten to arrows yet, but I think I see how `first` applies here. I'm completely okay with unsafe functions, to be clear. This is absolutely a case of I know more than I can prove to the type system. That said, I'm starting to question my premise, which was that this is normal, expected functionality in other languages. Outside of some scripting languages, I don't think that's actually true. Still, I'll leave the question up to see if anyone else chimes in.

Comment: It probably makes sense for you to ignore the "arrow" part of `first`, and pretend it was specialized to functions, which gives it the type `first :: (b -> c) -> (b, d) -> (c, d)` (it maps over the first element of a tuple)

Comment: @Joe Actually, one way to interpret my question is "how can I do this update and pull out the new value in one statement without writing a helper or upsetting the type checker?" I just tried it out, and `first fromJust $ updateLookupWithKey ...` does exactly that. If you'd like to write an answer to that effect, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying my own comments into an answer:

You could write `fromJustTuple` as `first fromJust` (where `first` is from [Control.Arrow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first)).

`first` has the type signature:

```hs
first :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)
```

But it probably makes sense for you to ignore the "arrow" part of first, and pretend it was specialized to functions, which gives it the type:

```hs
first :: (b -> c) -> (b, d) -> (c, d)
```

That is: it maps over the first element of a tuple.

---

Ultimately, I think your problem is that although you "can guarantee that the keys [you're] querying exist", you can't prove this to the type system, so unless you can change this, you're going to have to rely on unsafe functions like `fromJust`, or get incomplete pattern match warnings.

Comment: @thisisrandy I would use `first (fromMaybe default)`  (for a suitable value of `default`, maybe even `error "This key is supposed to exist!"`).  Since it is not guaranteed by the type system, you might have made a mistake, and this is great place to document that...

Answer (score 3):

I think the cause of the difficulty is that `updateLookupWithKey` is just not the right tool. Why not use [`alterF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:alterF)?

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

import Data.Maybe

update :: (Ord k, Num a) => (a -> a) -> k -> Map k a -> (a, Map k a)
update f = M.alterF (\old -> let new = f (fromMaybe 0 old) in (new, Just new))

incr :: (Ord k, Num a) => k -> Map k a -> (a, Map k a)
incr = update (+1)

decr :: (Ord k, Num a) => k -> Map k a -> (a, Map k a)
decr = update (subtract 1)
```

Now the only appearance of `Maybe` is to cover when the key is actually absent from the `Map`, and it defaults the associated value to 0 in that case.

Comment: This is very helpful in terms of different ways of thinking about the problem, but I want to point out that its semantics differ from those in my question in an important way: it would indicate a programming error in my case if a key were not present in the `Map`, so I would want an error at runtime. This solution hides that possibility behind a default value.

Comment: @thisisrandy It doesn't have to. You can easily modify the function passed to `alterF` to report the error however you like. That's the nice thing about `alterF`.

Comment: Right, I guess I could just use `fromJust` where you used `fromMaybe`. I tried doing that just now and ran into two issues. First, the compiler complains about the monomorphism restriction, which I just turned off with the appropriate language pragma. After that, there are errors like "Could not deduce (Ord k1) from the context: (Ord k, Num a)..." that I'm struggling to understand. Could you explain what's going on?

Comment: Do you happen to modify it into `fromJust 0 old`? Which is type error.

Comment: @Abastro No, I meant I copied Carl's code verbatim and got the errors mentioned above. I would have tried modifying it after having seen it working as is but didn't get that far.

Comment: @thisisrandy Odd. I could swear I tested it before posting. Well, a minor refactoring resolves that. Post updated.

Comment: @Carl Wonderful. Aside from the explicit signature for `update` (which I tried myself and which made no difference in the original formulation) I don't at all understand the difference between the two definitions. Could you provide some guidance? I suspect it has something to do with the multiple function definition syntax you used in the original, of which I was previously unfamiliar.